# VBA - Sparklines - different results while stepping through and running the code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with sparklines in my macro in VBA in excel.
In the debug, step through mode it works fine, however on RUN the sparklines are completely wrong, they are in the same areas, but seem to cover other data.
I have no idea what may be the problem at this point.

Here is the code:
* the pivot tables copied are (private) variables defined earlier

```
Sub DashboardMarket()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastColD As Integer, lastColD2 As Integer, lastRowD As Integer

Dim ptDM1 As PivotTable, ptDM2 As PivotTable, ptDM3 As PivotTable, ptDM4 As 
PivotTable

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
    If DoesSheetExist("Dashboard Market") = True Then
        If MsgBox("Do you wish to update existing Market Dashboard?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
        .Sheets("Dashboard Market").Delete
        .Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("data")).Name = "Dashboard Market"
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    Else: .Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("data")).Name = "Dashboard Market"
    End If
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard Market")
ws.Select

scdpt4.TableRange2.Cells.Resize(, scdpt4.TableRange2.Columns.Count + 2).Copy         
Destination:=ws.Cells(5, 2)
lastColD = 1 + scdpt4.TableRange2.Columns.Count + 2
lastRowD = 4 + scdpt4.TableRange2.Rows.Count
Set ptDM1 = ws.Cells(5, 2).PivotTable

    'create sparklines
    Range(Cells(ptDM1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD)).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, _
    SourceData:=Range(ptDM1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(lastRowD, lastColD - 2)).Address
    'format sparklines
    With Range(Cells(ptDM1.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD)).SparklineGroups.Item(1)
        .LineWeight = 1.1
        .Points.Markers.Visible = True
        .Points.Markers.Color.ColorIndex = 3
        .SeriesColor.ColorIndex = 32
        .SeriesColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

scdpt5.TableRange2.Cells.Resize(, scdpt5.TableRange2.Columns.Count + 2).Copy 
Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, 2)

Set ptDM2 = ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, 2).PivotTable

lastRowD = 1 + lastRowD + scdpt5.TableRange2.Rows.Count

    'create sparklines
    Range(Cells(ptDM2.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD)).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, _
    SourceData:=Range(ptDM2.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD - 2)).Address
    'format sparklines
    With Range(Cells(ptDM2.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD), ws.Cells(lastRowD, lastColD)).SparklineGroups.Item(1)
        .LineWeight = 1.1
        .Points.Markers.Visible = True
        .Points.Markers.Color.ColorIndex = 3
        .SeriesColor.ColorIndex = 32
        .SeriesColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

pt1.TableRange2.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(5, lastColD + 2)
lastRowD = 4 + pt1.TableRange2.Rows.Count
pt2.TableRange2.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, lastColD + 2)
lastRowD = 1 + lastRowD + pt2.TableRange2.Rows.Count
pt3.TableRange2.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, lastColD + 2)
lastRowD = 1 + lastRowD + pt3.TableRange2.Rows.Count
pt4.TableRange2.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, lastColD + 2)
lastRowD = 1 + lastRowD + pt4.TableRange2.Rows.Count
pt5.TableRange2.Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, lastColD + 2)
lastRowD = 1 + lastRowD + pt5.TableRange2.Rows.Count

lastColD = 1 + lastColD + pt1.TableRange2.Columns.Count

With ws.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, lastColD))
.MergeCells = True
.Value = "COMMUNICATED DISCOUNTS"
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.Font.Bold = True
.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
.Font.ColorIndex = 2
.Font.Size = 16
End With

pp_pt1.TableRange2.Cells.Resize(, pp_pt1.TableRange2.Columns.Count + 2).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(5, lastColD + 2)
lastRowD = 4 + pp_pt1.TableRange2.Rows.Count
lastColD2 = 1 + lastColD + pp_pt1.TableRange2.Columns.Count + 2

Set ptDM3 = ws.Cells(5, lastColD + 2).PivotTable

    'create sparklines
    Range(Cells(ptDM3.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD2), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD2)).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, _
    SourceData:=Range(ptDM3.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(lastRowD, lastColD2 - 2)).Address
    'format sparklines
    With Range(Cells(ptDM3.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD2), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD2)).SparklineGroups.Item(1)
        .LineWeight = 1.1
        .Points.Markers.Visible = True
        .Points.Markers.Color.ColorIndex = 3
        .SeriesColor.ColorIndex = 32
        .SeriesColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

pp_pt2.TableRange2.Cells.Resize(, pp_pt2.TableRange2.Columns.Count + 2).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, lastColD + 2)


Set ptDM4 = ws.Cells(lastRowD + 2, lastColD + 2).PivotTable

lastRowD = 1 + lastRowD + pp_pt2.TableRange2.Rows.Count

    'create sparklines
    Range(Cells(ptDM4.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD2), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD2)).SparklineGroups.Add Type:=xlSparkLine, _
    SourceData:=Range(ptDM4.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(lastRowD, lastColD2 - 2)).Address
    'format sparklines
    With Range(Cells(ptDM4.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).Row, lastColD2), Cells(lastRowD, lastColD2)).SparklineGroups.Item(1)
        .LineWeight = 1.1
        .Points.Markers.Visible = True
        .Points.Markers.Color.ColorIndex = 3
        .SeriesColor.ColorIndex = 32
        .SeriesColor.TintAndShade = 0
    End With

With ws.Range(Cells(3, lastColD + 2), Cells(3, lastColD2))
.MergeCells = True
.Value = "PROMO PRESSURE"
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.Font.Bold = True
.Interior.ColorIndex = 32
.Font.ColorIndex = 2
.Font.Size = 16
End With

With ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastColD2))
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
.Interior.ColorIndex = 32
.Font.ColorIndex = 2
End With


ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False

ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit



End Sub
```

Comment: The firts thing I notice is that your `Range` objects are not defined to any particular sheets in some places - could be an issue... you've got a sheet.select command in there even though you've set ws to = the sheet you select...

Comment: You have **several** undeclared/unassigned references including **`scdpt4, scdpt5, pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pp_pt1, pp_pt2`**.  I'd suggest you start by adding `Option Explicit` as the first line of [every] module [forever] to help ensure the proper handling of variables, objects, etc, by "forcing" proper declaration.

Comment: ashleedawg As I've written: * the pivot tables copied are (private) variables defined earlier, so this is not a problem i think
@jamheadart yes this command just changes the view to that shet while i do step through, it is just for that, but i'll look into the ranges

Comment: Yup it's just a potential problem - when you use ws.Select then all the un-defined `Range` objects after that should be referring to the ActiveSheet (e.g. ws cos you selected it) so it should work ok... in theory... but for total code clarity and preventing random button clicks or other events affecting this, it's best to make sure your `Range` is also preceded by its `worksheet` object e.g. `ws.Range(...)`

Comment: @jamheadart yea I keep forgetting about it, when i'll look into it today i'll firstly check the ranges out, thanks for answering :)

Comment: No probs, hope it helps! Seems to be what the problem is pointing at - runs ok when stepping through but automated it seems to point to other data... I definitely had those issues before and it was definitely due to that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally forgot to post about it, but the solution I came up with was as easy as they come, I just selected the data body of the new copy of a pivot table, so: `pt.DataBodyRange.Select` Before creating sparklines, every time it is done. Does anybody know what was the cause and solution without using Selection?